# Swift: Should I validate receipts Consumables

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I am at the point of validating receipts. However, I am curious if it is mandatory to validate the receipt of a Consumable? It is being stored in the Keychain as a virtual credit system, so not jailbreak worthy. However, I cannot find information on here.

Answer (score 1):

Consumables aren't stored in the receipt or at least not forever.

> Consumable in-app purchases remain in the receipt until you call finishTransaction(_:). Maintain and manage records of consumables on a server if needed.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique)